# godot4 first person sliding issue

Tags: camera, godot, gdscript, godot4

After following these tutorials (first person controller series by `https://www.youtube.com/@lukky.`) and making a first person controller in godot4.

Every time I finish sliding, my camera snaps back to the front. But how can I avoid that and instead keep the position? Better explanation: I don't like it how after you slide, you snap back to your front. I want to just continue looking at was I was looking, so I don't have to move my mouse again, and can instantly go.

My code:

```
extends CharacterBody3D

# Player nodes

@onready var neck = $Neck
@onready var head = $Neck/Head
@onready var eyes = $Neck/Head/Eyes

@onready var standing_collision_shape = $StandingCollisionShape
@onready var crouching_collisiong_shape = $CrouchingCollisiongShape
@onready var up_ray_cast = $UpRayCast
@onready var camera_3d = $Neck/Head/Eyes/Camera3D
@onready var animation_player = $Neck/Head/Eyes/AnimationPlayer

# Speed vars

var current_speed = 5.0

const walking_speed = 5.0
const sprinting_speed = 8.0
const crouching_speed = 3.0

# States

var walking = false
var sprinting = false
var crouching = false
var free_looking = false
var sliding = false

# Slide vars

var slide_timer = 0.0
var slide_timer_max = 1.0
var slide_vector = Vector2.ZERO
var slide_speed = 13.0

# Head bobbing vars

const head_bobbing_sprinting_speed = 22.0
const head_bobbing_walking_speed = 14.0
const head_bobbing_crouching_speed = 10.0

const head_bobbing_sprinting_intensity = 0.2
const head_bobbing_walking_intensity = 0.1
const head_bobbing_crouching_intensity = 0.05

var head_bobbing_vector = Vector2.ZERO
var head_bobbing_index = 0.0
var head_bobbing_current_intensity = 0.0

# Movement vars

const jump_velocity = 5.5

var crouching_depth = -0.5

var lerp_speed = 10.0

var air_lerp_speed = 3.0

var free_look_tilt_amount = 8

var last_velocity = Vector3.ZERO

# Input vars

var direction = Vector3.ZERO
const mouse_sens = 0.1


# Get the gravity from the project settings to be synced with RigidBody nodes.
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/3d/default_gravity")


func _ready():
    Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED)
    

func _input(event):
    # Mouse looking logic
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        if free_looking:
            neck.rotate_y(deg_to_rad(-event.relative.x * mouse_sens))
            neck.rotation.y = clamp(neck.rotation.y, deg_to_rad(-120), deg_to_rad(120))
        else:
            rotate_y(deg_to_rad(-event.relative.x * mouse_sens))
        head.rotate_x(deg_to_rad(-event.relative.y * mouse_sens))
        head.rotation.x = clamp(head.rotation.x, deg_to_rad(-89), deg_to_rad(89))
    
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    # Getting movement input
    var input_dir = Input.get_vector("left", "right", "forward", "backward")
    
    # Handle movement state
    
    # Crouching
    if Input.is_action_pressed("crouch") || sliding:
        current_speed = lerp(current_speed, crouching_speed, delta * lerp_speed)
        head.position.y = lerp(head.position.y, crouching_depth, delta * lerp_speed)
        
        crouching_collisiong_shape.disabled = false
        standing_collision_shape.disabled = true
        
        # Slide begin logic
        if sprinting && input_dir != Vector2.ZERO:
            sliding = true
            slide_timer = slide_timer_max
            slide_vector = input_dir
            free_looking = true
        
        walking = false
        sprinting = false
        crouching = true

    elif not up_ray_cast.is_colliding():
        
        # Standing 
        
        standing_collision_shape.disabled = false
        crouching_collisiong_shape.disabled = true
        head.position.y = lerp(head.position.y, 0.0, delta * lerp_speed)
        if Input.is_action_pressed("sprint"):
            # Sprinting
            current_speed = lerp(current_speed, sprinting_speed, delta * lerp_speed)
            
            walking = false
            sprinting = true
            crouching = false
        else:
            # Walking
            current_speed = lerp(current_speed, walking_speed, delta * lerp_speed)
            
            walking = true
            sprinting = false
            crouching = false
    
    
    # Handle free looking
    if Input.is_action_pressed("free_look") || sliding:
        free_looking = true
        
        if sliding:
            eyes.rotation.z = lerp(eyes.rotation.z, -deg_to_rad(7.0), delta * lerp_speed)
        else:
            eyes.rotation.z = -deg_to_rad(neck.rotation.y * free_look_tilt_amount)
    else:
        free_looking = false
        neck.rotation.y = lerp(neck.rotation.y, 0.0, delta * lerp_speed)
        eyes.rotation.z = lerp(eyes.rotation.z, 0.0, delta * lerp_speed)
    
    # Hanle sliding
    if sliding:
        slide_timer -= delta
        if slide_timer <= 0:
            sliding = false
            free_looking = false
    
    # Handle headbob
    if sprinting:
        head_bobbing_current_intensity = head_bobbing_sprinting_intensity
        head_bobbing_index += head_bobbing_sprinting_speed * delta
    elif walking:
        head_bobbing_current_intensity = head_bobbing_walking_intensity
        head_bobbing_index += head_bobbing_walking_speed * delta
    elif crouching:
        head_bobbing_current_intensity = head_bobbing_crouching_intensity
        head_bobbing_index += head_bobbing_crouching_speed * delta
    
    if is_on_floor() && !sliding && input_dir != Vector2.ZERO:
        head_bobbing_vector.y = sin(head_bobbing_index)
        head_bobbing_vector.x = sin(head_bobbing_index / 2) + 0.5
        
        eyes.position.y = lerp(eyes.position.y, head_bobbing_vector.y * (head_bobbing_current_intensity / 2.0), delta * lerp_speed) # can tweak 2.0
        eyes.position.x = lerp(eyes.position.x, head_bobbing_vector.x * head_bobbing_current_intensity, delta * lerp_speed)
    else:
        eyes.position.y = lerp(eyes.position.y, 0.0, delta * lerp_speed)
        eyes.position.x = lerp(eyes.position.x, 0.0, delta * lerp_speed)
    
    
    
    
    
    # ------------MOVEMENT CODE------------ #
    
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y -= gravity * delta

    # Handle Jump.
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = jump_velocity
        sliding = false # MAYBE LATER MAKE "C" SLIDE CANCEL INSTEAD OF SPACE (But still keep slide jumping)
        animation_player.play("jump")
        
    # Handle landing
    if is_on_floor():
        if last_velocity.y < -10.0:
            animation_player.play("roll")
        elif last_velocity.y < -4.0:
            animation_player.play("landing")

    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    # As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
    if is_on_floor():
        direction = lerp(direction, transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y).normalized(), delta * lerp_speed)
    else:
        if input_dir != Vector2.ZERO:
            direction = lerp(direction, transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y).normalized(), delta * air_lerp_speed)
    
    if sliding:
        direction = (transform.basis * Vector3(slide_vector.x, 0, slide_vector.y)).normalized()
        current_speed = (slide_timer + 0.1) * slide_speed
    
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction.x * current_speed
        velocity.z = direction.z * current_speed
        
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, current_speed)
        velocity.z = move_toward(velocity.z, 0, current_speed)
    
    last_velocity = velocity

    # RESPAWN
    if position.y < -10.0:
        position = Vector3(0, 0, 0)
        last_velocity = Vector3.ZERO
    
    move_and_slide()
```

[image]

Comment: For what I read in your code you have two ways to control the camera, and you switch based on the `free_looking` variable, and in the "sliding" part of the code you set it to `free_looking = false`, does changing to to `true` do what you want?

Comment: no. I tried that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the issue:

```
    # Handle free looking
    if Input.is_action_pressed("free_look") || sliding:
        free_looking = true
        
        if sliding:
            eyes.rotation.z = lerp(eyes.rotation.z, -deg_to_rad(7.0), delta * lerp_speed)
        else:
            eyes.rotation.z = -deg_to_rad(neck.rotation.y * free_look_tilt_amount)
    else:
        free_looking = false
        neck.rotation.y = lerp(neck.rotation.y, 0.0, delta * lerp_speed)
        eyes.rotation.z = lerp(eyes.rotation.z, 0.0, delta * lerp_speed)
```

This code will `lerp` the rotations when the character is not sliding and the player is not pressing `"free_look"`.

*I want to mention that this use of `lerp` is frame rate dependent, and move on.*

Now let us take inventory of the rotations affected by the code above:

- `eyes.rotation.z`
- `neck.rotation.y`

And let us compare with the code that actually lets you look around:

```
func _input(event):
    # Mouse looking logic
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        if free_looking:
            neck.rotate_y(deg_to_rad(-event.relative.x * mouse_sens))
            neck.rotation.y = clamp(neck.rotation.y, deg_to_rad(-120), deg_to_rad(120))
        else:
            rotate_y(deg_to_rad(-event.relative.x * mouse_sens))
        head.rotate_x(deg_to_rad(-event.relative.y * mouse_sens))
        head.rotation.x = clamp(head.rotation.x, deg_to_rad(-89), deg_to_rad(89))
```

Here we move:

- `neck.rotation.y`
- `head.rotation.x`
- `rotation.y`

And we find that the overlap is `neck.rotation.y`.

We also observe that when `free_looking` the code rotates the `neck` around the `y` axis, and otherwise it moves the body around the `y` axis.

Thus, it seems that what we want is to transfer the rotation of the neck to the body when it stops `free_looking` (here I'm doing instantly):

```
    # Handle free looking
    if Input.is_action_pressed("free_look") || sliding:
        free_looking = true
        
        if sliding:
            eyes.rotation.z = lerp(eyes.rotation.z, -deg_to_rad(7.0), delta * lerp_speed)
        else:
            eyes.rotation.z = -deg_to_rad(neck.rotation.y * free_look_tilt_amount)
    else:
        if free_looking:
            rotation.y = neck.rotation.y
            neck.rotation.y = 0.0
            free_looking = false
        
        eyes.rotation.z = lerp(eyes.rotation.z, 0.0, delta * lerp_speed)
```

---

Another option is to remove the `neck` and always rotate the body around the `y` axis, and don't reset it ever, which seems to work on my tests. However, I do not know if you need the orientation of the body to remain the same for other purposes.

```
func _input(event):
    # Mouse looking logic
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        if free_looking:
            rotate_y(deg_to_rad(-event.relative.x * mouse_sens))
            rotation.y = clamp(rotation.y, deg_to_rad(-120), deg_to_rad(120))
        else:
            rotate_y(deg_to_rad(-event.relative.x * mouse_sens))
        head.rotate_x(deg_to_rad(-event.relative.y * mouse_sens))
        head.rotation.x = clamp(head.rotation.x, deg_to_rad(-89), deg_to_rad(89))
```

```
    # Handle free looking
    if Input.is_action_pressed("free_look") || sliding:
        free_looking = true
        
        if sliding:
            eyes.rotation.z = lerp(eyes.rotation.z, -deg_to_rad(7.0), delta * lerp_speed)
        else:
            eyes.rotation.z = -deg_to_rad(rotation.y * free_look_tilt_amount)
    else:
        free_looking = false
        eyes.rotation.z = lerp(eyes.rotation.z, 0.0, delta * lerp_speed)
```

---

It is also possible to smoothly transfer the rotation between `neck` and body. The gist of it is that every frame you remove rotation from the `neck` and add it to the body.

*I'm not a fan of using `lerp` this way, so I'll leave the exercise to you.*

Comment: can you please send me your project if possible?

Comment: @Coding_Guy I made this as part of a project where I throw stuff I'm experimenting with, so I would rather not. Instead I made a gist with the player script and the scene file: https://gist.github.com/theraot/ae77307db79eaf0c4beebb27d218bf19 - they were in the folder "res://scenes/world/" in the project. I hope that helps. Addendum: I remind you that I proposed multiple solutions, so that is just the last thing I tried. Also: I use static typing for everything in my code.